# Firefox 10.0.1 not playing html mp4 video

Tags: javascript, flash, html

**I have the following code for playing video into the web page :**

```
<video width="420" height="345" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="/common/videos/EPyl1LgNtoQ.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="/common/videos/EPyl1LgNtoQ.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="/common/videos/EPyl1LgNtoQ.webm" type="video/webm" />

        <object width="320" height="240" src="/common/videos/EPyl1LgNtoQ.mp4">
            <embed width="320" height="240" src="/common/videos/EPyl1LgNtoQ.swf">
            Your browser does not support video
            </embed>
        </object>            
    </video>
```

**The file is in .mp4 format and I have firefox 10.0.1 version and chrome 17.0 version.**

**The video is playing on chrome but not on firefox.**

**It displaying player but not playing the video over it.**

**I want to play it on firefox so how it will play on it. I am going through lot of tutorials but not finding any solution.**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Did you check your server if it delivers the right MIME-type for video/ogg and/or video/webm? It's not enabled by default. In Apache, you have to modify the .htaccess file or the file mime.types (depending on your configuration and rights).

Comment: @JanPetzold : I modified my .htaccess but still same problem

Comment: Hm. Your source code looks OK. You restarted Apache/reloaded the configuration, did you :)

Did you check with Firebug that the file is transferred with the correct MIME type or at least that it gets downloaded at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your apache .htaccess file like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/ogg .oga
```

Try this I hope i'll work for you.

Comment: Why did you mention the RewriteRules?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [videoJS.com](http://videojs.com/) - it's an opensource abstraction layer over HTML5 video technologies (with a Flash Player fallback for legacy browsers).